# Missing whisk.system namespace in OpenWhisk Api

Tags: kubernetes, openwhisk

I am experiencing a strange behaviour where I deployed OpenWhisk on Kubernetes and after the Deployments, I can call the API, but the whisk.system namespace is nowhere to be found. I only have a Guest Namespace.

Is the whisk.system Namespace not deployed with the OpenWhisk?
Or did some component Fail on deploymend?

I am happy to provide further logs and yaml when needed.

```
 2018/07/04 11:19:59 [alert] 26#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2018/07/04 11:19:59 [alert] 27#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
==&gt; /var/log/api-gateway/access.log &lt;==
 ==&gt; /var/log/api-gateway/error.log &lt;==
 ==&gt; /var/log/api-gateway/gateway_error.log &lt;==
 ==&gt; /var/log/api-gateway/management.log &lt;==
2018/07/04 11:20:09 Executing Reload Cmd
2018/07/04 11:20:09 Executing sync cmd: api-gateway -s reload
2018/07/04 11:20:09 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
sync stdout | ''
2018/07/04 11:20:09 done
2018/07/04 11:20:09 done
2018/07/04 11:20:09 [alert] 33#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2018/07/04 11:20:09 [alert] 34#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2018/07/04 11:20:09 [alert] 35#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
2018/07/04 11:20:09 [alert] 36#0: setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, 524288) failed (1: Operation not permitted)
 ==&gt; /var/log/api-gateway/error.log &lt;==
2018/07/04 11:20:09 [notice] 30#0: signal process started
2018/07/04 11:20:19 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
sync stdout | ''
2018/07/04 11:20:19 done
2018/07/04 11:20:29 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
sync stdout | ''
2018/07/04 11:20:29 done
2018/07/04 11:20:39 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
sync stdout | ''
2018/07/04 11:20:39 done
2018/07/04 11:20:49 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
sync stdout | ''
2018/07/04 11:20:49 done
2018/07/04 11:20:59 Executing sync cmd: echo ''
2018/07/04 11:20:59 done
sync stdout | ''
```